# NIntegrate a singular function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to do this integral numerically:

```
NIntegrate[(1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(1/2) - 1/((x - 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(
   1/2))^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, 0}]
```

But for different methods in NIntegrate, I got different results:

GlobalAdaptive: 6.28318

MonteCarlo: 5.66018

AdaptiveMonteCarlo: 6.01981

QuasiMonteCarlo: 5.15901

AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo: 4.59813

I am not sure which one is more accurate. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The value given by `GlobalAdaptive` is very close to 2 pi.  It should be more accurate than the other methods, though it does give warnings suggesting that the answer might be doubtful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the precision and check what happens:

```
Table[
      NIntegrate[(1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(1/2) - 1/((x - 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(1/2))^2
      , {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, 0}
      , Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> n 1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 5 n]
, {n, 1, 8}
]
ListLogPlot[Abs[% - 2 π]]
```

[image]

And so, indeed, it appears that the integral converges to $2\pi$.

Comment: I found the integral interesting in itself and asked in the Mathematica forum how it would be solved analytically.  Adam there solved it beautifully:  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246406/show-integral-is-2-pi

Comment: @Dominic Cool, thank you for the link :-)

Comment: I have solved it analytically too. Thanks for your help!